# wordpress Get items by customer order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have [this](https://github.com/alenb/Contact-Form-7-WooCommerce/blob/master/cf7-woocommerce-products.php) plugin. It shows all products from woocommerce, but I want to show products from all Completed User Orders.

```
// Change product query settings here
$product_posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'numberposts' => -1,
) );

// Display product options
$values = array();
foreach ( $product_posts as $product ) {
    $values[] = $product->post_title;
}
```

Suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: This question is very badly asked, and you are not giving us data to work with.

Comment: I linked a full plugin code to GitHub. What information you need to know more?

Comment: You want us to help you get items by customer order, but we dont have any information about customers. And what order? etc, look at the github there is no customer information.